# How to Find the Unique Parameters by Connect AirDrop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, airdrop

I am trying to implement AirDrop feature in my iOS Application. However, I am unable to find any specific Parameters to pair two device via Airdrop,(pair Two iPhone device via Airdrop get Unique parameters ) Can someone please provide me with a sample, or a link, regarding the implementation of the AirDrop feature in iOS 7?

Any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks.
Shriram.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the [AirDrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html)